# In Sitecore Personalize, how can I use a Map in my decision table?

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize, decisioning

I am building a decision model with a programmable that returns a map. How can I use attributes from this map in a decision table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When returning a map from a programmable, the type in the settings needs to be changed to a Map. If the type is not updated, the output will be interpreted as a string by the platform.

[image]

**Decision Tables**

When using a Map from a programmable in a decision table, follow these steps:

1. Select the programmable as an input.
2. On the Add Input Column page,

   - enter the ‘Name of Column’ as it will appear in the decision table
   - Enter the ‘Map Key’, which is a reference to the attribute in the Map you want to use i.e. map name.attribute
   - Select the Type, depending on the data type of the attribute you are using.
     d.
3. Once the Input Column is added the decision table can be used as normal

Please see an example of the Input Column below:
[image]